# Set the value of a TextView, from an Alert

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I've got a Fragment (ActionBar Activity with 3 tabs) with a TextView
There is also a Button which open an Alert, in which there is Button and an EditText
What i would like to do, is to set the value of the Fragment's TextView to the value of the Alert's EditText, when clicking on the Button.
Here is what i tried to do (the method i show you is in the MAinActivity and not in the Fragment) :

```
    public void showTimePicker(Button but) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        final TimePicker t;

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_time);
        dialog.setTitle("Heure");

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePicker t = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.time_cri);

                /* THIS LINE MAKE A NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION */
                time.setText(getSelectedTime(t)); /* GET THE TIME FROM TIMEPICKER */
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        CriFragment f = (CriFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
        time = f.getTextView(); /* GETTER OF THE TEXTVIEW I'D LIKE TO SET */

        dialog.show();
    }
```

The line i pointed out make a nullPointerException (at onClick())
Thank you for reading !

Comment: Change  `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);` to  `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(yourActivity.this);`

Comment: where is `time` initialized? This  `time = f.getTextView()` failed?

Comment: Where and how are you declaring time TextView?

Comment: Yes thank you, time was not initialized good !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the TextView "time". Because the TextView "time" isn't initialized. You can use dialog.findViewById, not f.getTextView.

Comment: yes that's it thank you, except that i can't use findViewById because i have got multiple different buttons that can call this methos, but i already have the solution to this !!